# How to stop the automatic scrolling of a Memo control?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, windows-messages

In Windows 7, a memo control (`TMemo`) will scroll automatically after text is insterted (`Memo.Lines.Add(Path);`), which I do not want, because scrolling is done by myself.

How can I stop the automatic scrolling?

Comment: When the memo scrolls automatically?

Comment: when data is inserted.  code: lstFiles.Lines.Add(Path);. lstFiles is TMemo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Normally, adding text to a memo control scrolls the memo to the bottom of the inserted text. To prevent that, call `Lines.BeginUpdate` before adding text, and call `EndUpdate` afterwards:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.BeginUpdate;
  try
    Memo1.Lines.Add('...');
    Memo1.Lines.Add('...');
    ...
  finally
    Memo1.Lines.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This functions OK but have undesired side effect of flickering :-(. Setting DoubleBuffered property is of no benefit.

Comment: Can you explain why this works? In the documentation for `System.Classes.TStrings.BeginUpdate` it says "Some descendants of TStrings use this information to perform certain actions, such as telling a control to repaint, when updates are complete."

Comment: @New Because `TMemoStrings.SetUpdateState` is implemented the way it is.