# TMemo Scrolling in Delphi

Tags: delphi, scroll, tmemo

I am adding lines of text to a TMemo using : Memo1.Lines.Add(Text), which causes Memo1 to scroll to the bottom.

Is there any way to either stop it scrolling as I add lines, or force it to go back to the top when I finished?

I want a simple solution...

Thanks...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop the automatic scrolling of a Memo control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079906/how-to-stop-the-automatic-scrolling-of-a-memo-control)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use begin/end update for lines collection:

```
memo.Lines.BeginUpdate;
try
  memo.Lines.Add('test');
finally
  memo.Lines.EndUpdate;
end;
```

Comment: All this does is prevents the Memo from redrawing on each add.  It does not affect scrolling.

Comment: @ThomasJomphe: if it works, you should accept an answer

Answer (score 6):

Set the Memo's `SelStart` property to 0 and then send an [`EM_SCROLLCARET`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761637.aspx) message to the Memo.

```
Memo1.Lines.BeginUpdate;
try
  Memo1.Lines.Add(...);
  ...
  Memo1.SelStart := 0;
  Memo1.SelLength := 0;
  Memo1.Perform(EM_SCROLLCARET, 0, 0);
finally
  Memo1.Lines.EndUpdate;
end;
```